# Cannot find module 'passport' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: typescript, jwt, nestjs, nestjs-passport, nestjs-jwt

I am using @nestjs/passport. After running `npm run start:dev` I got an error, but the editor doesn't show an error

```
node_modules/@nestjs/passport/dist/passport/passport.serializer.d.ts:1:27 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'passport' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import * as passport from 'passport';
```

Input Code:

```typescript
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { UserRepository } from './user.repository';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';


@Module({
  imports:[
    PassportModule.register({defaultStrategy:'jwt'}),
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: 'topSecret51',
      signOptions:{
        expiresIn:3600,
      },
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserRepository]),
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Question [NestJS jwt-passport Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52969368/nestjs-jwt-passport-authentication?rq=1) looks related.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

this error occurs due to the node version. if you got this, update node version and reinstall passport module using `npm i --save @nestjs/passport passport`

Comment: What does `--save` do? Is there a reason that `npm install` doesn't work for this package?

Answer (score 23):

I had the same problem. But I did a rebuild and everything worked.
Removed the `dist` folder and then start again

```
rm -r dist
npm run start:dev
```

Comment: This works for me, make sure you also installed the next dependences: ```@nestjs/passport```  ```passport``` ```passport-jwt```

Answer (score 10):

Same issue here.

Solved it with `npm i @types/passport --save`

Answer (score 6):

Had the same problem, I solved it by running `$ npm i --save @nestjs/passport passport`.